# HLF v1.0.2 - installing chaincode signed by multiple owners

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Currently, by default it is possible to install chaincode that has only the signature of the identity of the node that is issuing the install transaction.

Q: how to setup fabric network to enforce the ability to install chaincode signed by defined owners?

My understanding is that current implementation allows admins to install different chaincodes on each peer using the same name and version. So, as long as these different chaincodes produce the same read/write set during endorsement phase the transaction will be positively validated later on. 
It could lead e.g. to a DoS attacks if ***single*** endorsing peer will be compromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question, and is in fact the point of an active [improvement](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-6042) targeted for 1.1 - to improve the lifecycle management of chaincode.

Quoting the JIRA:

> The chaincode lifecycle is implemented as an endorser transaction,
>   because it modifies the state database. However, all of the real
>   validation of the instantiation is actually done in an ad-hoc
>   psuedo-simulation style in the VSCC. Therefore, it makes sense to
>   remove the endorsement step, and simply perform all validation during
>   the commit phase.
>
> The channel config already supports this style of zero-endorsement,
>   validation-only transactions with multiple signatures, so it is a
>   natural fit for managing chaincode lifecycle. However, unlike channel
>   config operations which are processed by the orderer, chaincode
>   lifecycle falls entirely within the scope of of the peer and should
>   not require (nor is it desirable to require) the orderer's involvement
>   for these operations.

Comment: Can you provide Jira FAB number?

Comment: it is linked above (FAB-6042)